# Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: dll, asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

I'm trying to install Glimpse into a .NET MVC project, which is configured as an application in IIS7. I'm getting the error 'Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies'. I get this when I browse to my URL http://*mydomain*/*myapplication*/glimpse.axd

I installed the package into my project using:

nuget package manager console >

```
install-package glimpse
```

This gives me a Glimpse.Core dll in my project (not Glimpse.AspNet), which seems to be the issue.

I've gone through the Glimpse configuration here:

http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Configuration

And following the instructions, I've added this to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    ....
    <modules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      ....
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I also added this:

```
  <configSections>
    ....
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, 
Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
```

I've made sure that this line is appearing in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I then tried:

```
Uninstall-Package Glimpse
Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5
```

This seems to have put all of the correct web.config entries I need for using Glimpse.AspNet with MVC 5, however I still get the error.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by doing

```
install-package Glimpse.AspNet
```

Then doing a rebuild

I'm not sure if I needed the re-install of glimpse.aspnet, since it just replaced Glimpse.AspNet.1.8.6 with 1.9.2. Maybe I just needed to do a rebuild after:

```
Uninstall-Package Glimpse
Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5
```

I'm guessing that to install Glimpse all I originally needed was:

```
Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5
```

Then rebuild.

I needed to have Glimpse running on a test server, and the Glimpse install only added its configuration to web.config and didn't add it to Web.Debug.config. I had to copy over the Glimpse configuration manually. Here are the web.config entries that Glimpse needs to work with MVC 5:

```
<!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
    <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
<httpModules>
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
</httpHandlers>
```

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="Glimpse" />
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

... and right at the end of the .config file:

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <!-- 
          For more information on how to configure Glimpse, please visit http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration
          or access {your site}/Glimpse.axd for even more details and a Configuration Tool to support you. 
  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your application. the project you loaded Glimpse into was not building, and that is why there was a problem.When you build the project individually it works.